# Unclear structure of authentification endpoint for changenotifications from graph api

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, request, microsoft-graph-api

I try to subscribe for the User[id]/messages source at the developer programm exchange server.
How i have to structure my request against graph is totally clear. and works but how i have to process the authentication request of Graph is unclear. I know i have to aswer with a 200 OK but i also have to send the processed token back according to some Tutorials. But not a single tutorial shows a example authentication endpoint.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/changeNotifications")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ChangeNotificationEndpoint(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
        {
            _logger.Debug("Anfrage von Graph an Vif erhalten");

            

            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = /* The unclear section */ ;
            };
        }
```

I have tried to to follow some tutorials but each tutorial lacks of an example endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for Notification endpoint validation:

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?tabs=http#notification-endpoint-validation

Hope this helps.